# Rails: Give votes weight based on how long ago they were cast

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I set up a voting system in which in my user view is a form for a separate model called "votes", which consists only of a submit button. Every time the button is pressed, a new vote instance is created, and then `user.vote.count` returns the total. However, I want newer votes to have more weight, so for example a vote cast a day ago would count for 6 votes, and with each day that passes it would lose one vote, so after 6 days it wouldn't count at all. How would I go about doing this?

I'm using Rails 4.0.10

Users controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.votes.build
    @vote = Vote.new
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @users = User.all
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end


  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name)
    end

end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes

  def vote
    (self.votes.count )
  end
end
```

Votes controller:

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @vote = Vote.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @vote = Vote.new
    @votes = Vote.all
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @vote = @user.votes.create(vote_params)
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  end

  private

    def vote_params
      params.permit(:user_id)
    end

end
```

Vote model:

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

User view:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @vote] do |f| %>
  <input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="#{@user.id}" />
  <%= f.submit ": )", :onclick => 'alert("Voted up!")' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You need to supply a lot more information, such as showing the related code. As is we're going to do a lot of guessing what you're implemented.

Comment: I don't think any of the code I have would really be helpful, but I'll post what I have.

Comment: Add the *minimal amount necessary to duplicate the problem.* Anything beyond that wastes everyone's time.

Comment: That's what I tried to do.

Comment: You're going to need to create a query that scores the votes based on your rules that you mentioned above. If you post your data model for `votes` I give you an outline for the query.

Comment: @John Sorry, I'm new to Rails. Does data model refer to something other than the models/votes.rb file? If not, that's all the code I've written for it so far.

Comment: The model files don't show the columns of your table which might be helpful in this case. I posted an outline below that might give you a starting point if I understand you problem correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be something along these lines if you're using PostgreSQL.

```
User.votes
  .select('SUM(6 - extract(day from now() - created_at)) as score')
  .where("created_at >= current_date - interval '6' day")
```

This takes all votes that are 6 days old or less. It then scores each vote based on how old it is (6 - age). Finally it takes the sum of the individual scores.